# SSIS query running very slowly in job from catalog. wait_type: ASYNC_NETWORK_IO

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I have an SSIS package as part of a project. When run from my machine via SSIS, it takes about 15 minutes to process 15M records.
Once deployed to the catalog on the server and run through a job, it's been going for over 2 hours now.

This particular package is moving data on the server itself (in staging), so there's no network bottlenecks.

here are some statistics from SP_WHO3:

cpu_time: 484482

requested_memory_kb: 2469520

granted_memory_kb: 2469520

ideal_memory_kb: 14508048

query_cost: 85.3073051231772

wait_type: ASYNC_NETWORK_IO

Looking at the resource monitor on the server, I see that disk I/O is terribly high (of course), mostly by the System process, at ~190,000,000 B/Sec, and coming in at a far second is sqlserver.exe at ~300,000 B/Sec

The package is configured with BufferTempStoragePath set to c:\temp\
DefaultBufferMaxRows = 10,000
DefaultBufferSize = 10,485,760

Where should I go on looking in order to find the root cause for this slow execution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

ASYNC_NETWORK_IO is caused by the client code not consuming the rows coming from SQL fast enough

Have you deployed the package to the same server you are querying data from?
Because to process those rows requires memory that SQL server will be probably be using.

Running it locally on your PC separates this load.

"System process, at ~190,000,000 B/Sec" might be a lot of memory paging too where you are thrashing disk and memory because you have low memory.

Personally, I would always use a separate dedicated ETL (SSIS) server.

However, I would review your SQL Server max memory and reduce it to allow the SSIS package to run.

Comment: This is on the dedicated ETL Server. Sorry I didn't clarify this. 
The source of this package is the mirror database, and its destination is the staging DB. All on the same server.

Why would REDUCING max memory help to address this problem? (the server has 16GB of memory, and about 90% of it is in use (This is a Dev server))

Comment: @Ethan1701 I assumed SSIS and SQL Engine on the same server